# How to make php function as string do real function?

Tags: php

lets assume that i have function named `printuser()`

now if i have string like

```
$myFunction = 'printuser()';
```

how i can run this string as function ? so it should do the `printuser()` function

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  There is probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `$myFunction` to specify which function to run, you can do something like

```
$myFunction = 'printuser';
$myFunction();
```

This is called a "[variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)", and is slightly less dangerous than `eval`.  (You can call any existing function, but you can't run arbitrary code.)

Be warned, though: if `printuser` doesn't exist, the script will die.  You might consider checking for the function's existence before calling it.

```
$myFunction = 'printuser';
if (function_exists($myFunction))
    $myFunction();
else
    throw new BadFunctionCallException("Function '$myFunction' doesn't exist");
```

Replace the `throw` with whatever you want to do if the function isn't there.  That's just an example.

Comment: Wow! it is great way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at **[`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)**. You'll need to change your string a little (no brackets).

Comment: +1 `call_user_func` makes it explicit what you're trying to do in your code ... which is much better for poor Joe Programmer who has to maintain it down the road and doesn't inappropriately expose you to the dangers of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [eval](http://php.net/eval).
2. You almost never ever ever should do this. There's almost always a better, safer, more secure way.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Hence the "don't do this" note.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$myFunction = 'printuser()';
# Remove brakets
$myFunction = rtrim($myFunction, "()");
# Call Function Directly
$myFunction();
```

For validation you can use `is_callable`

```
is_callable($myFunction) and $myFunction();
```

[Simple Demo](http://3v4l.org/Fl8v3)

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion with a fail safe:

```
$function = str_replace("()", "", $input);
if( function_exists($function))
{
  $function();
}
else
{
  // ignore or show an error
}
```